# function call inside a function in php not working

Tags: php

This code is a function calling a function in php. The function call is never called.

```
function saveSubject(){
    $result = mysql_query("select * from term where description='".$_POST['term']."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
    global $term;
    $term = $row[0];
    $x=1;
    while(isset($_POST['subCode'.$x])and isset($_POST['subTitle'.$x]) and isset($_POST['subUnit'.$x])){
            $code = $_POST['subCode'.$x];
            $title = $_POST['subTitle'.$x];
            $unit = $_POST['subUnit'.$x];
            $query = "INSERT INTO subject(subcode, description, units, termid)
                VALUES('".$code."','".$title."',".$unit.",".$term.")";
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from subject where subcode='".$code."'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                $message = "Subject Code : ".$code;
                prompt($message);
            }else{
                mysql_query($query);
                savePre($code, $x);
                }
            $x++;
        }
}
function savePre($code, $y){
$pre = mysql_query("SELECT subject.subcode from subject left join term
                    on term.termid=subject.termid
                    left join curriculum on term.termid = curriculum.curriculumid
                    where term.courseid =".$_POST['course']);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pre, MYSQL_NUM)){
        $c = $row[0].$y;
        if(isset($_POST[$c])){
            $result = mysql_query("Select * from pre_requisite where pre_requisites=".$row[0]."and subject=".$code);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                $message = "";
            }else{
                mysql_query("INSERT into pre_requisites(pre_requisite, subject)
                    values (".$row[0].", ".$code.")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling function savePre() in saveSubjec() but the calling is not working. I cannot find out what is wrong. Please help!

Comment: because its not executing `else` statement..make sure `mysql_num_rows($result)` return `0` then your function will work

Comment: When you say the call is not working, what do you mean? Are you getting an error? Is the database updating? Try adding this to the end of every mysql_query() `or die mysql_error();`

Comment: `echo` something before function call to see if the `else` executing or not.

Comment: write the `savePre` function above of the `saveSubjec` and then try.

Comment: @DipeshParmar I have done that. The query before that call is executing well.

Comment: @dale there's no error at all.

Answer (score 1):

Simple...

You code is

```
$query = "INSERT INTO subject(subcode, description, units, termid)
    VALUES('".$code."','".$title."',".$unit.",".$term.")";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from subject where subcode='".$code."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $message = "Subject Code : ".$code;
    prompt($message);
}else{
    mysql_query($query);
    savePre($code, $x);
}
```

from above code you can imagine that you are inserting record to `database` and then selecting that record using `subcode` match `where condition` so it will always return `1` as `output` so your `else condition` **will never get execute**.

That's the reason why you are not able to call `savePre` function.

Comment: he does not execute insert query before select.

Comment: ohhh Yes i did not realized it. +1 for u

Answer (score 0):

You want to define savePre() function above the saveSubject() function. Use this.

```
function savePre($code, $y)
{
 $pre = mysql_query("SELECT subject.subcode from subject left join term
                on term.termid=subject.termid
                left join curriculum on term.termid = curriculum.curriculumid
                where term.courseid =".$_POST['course']);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pre, MYSQL_NUM))
 {
    $c = $row[0].$y;
    if(isset($_POST[$c]))
    {
        $result = mysql_query("Select * from pre_requisite where pre_requisites=".$row[0]."and subject=".$code);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $message = "";
        }else{
            mysql_query("INSERT into pre_requisites(pre_requisite, subject)
                values (".$row[0].", ".$code.")");
        }
    }
 }
}

function saveSubject()
{
 $result = mysql_query("select * from term where description='".$_POST['term']."'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
 global $term;
 $term = $row[0];
 $x=1;
 while(isset($_POST['subCode'.$x])and isset($_POST['subTitle'.$x]) and isset($_POST['subUnit'.$x]))
 {
        $code = $_POST['subCode'.$x];
        $title = $_POST['subTitle'.$x];
        $unit = $_POST['subUnit'.$x];

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from subject where subcode='".$code."'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $message = "Subject Code : ".$code;
            prompt($message);
        }
        else
        {
           $query = "INSERT INTO subject(subcode, description, units, termid)
            VALUES('".$code."','".$title."',".$unit.",".$term.")";
            mysql_query($query);

            savePre($code, $x);
            }
        $x++;
   }
}
```